# Randomly pick a list that contains the specific element

Tags: python

Given several lists

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,6,7,8],[2,3,4],[1,9,10,13]]
```

Is there an easy method to randomly pick a list that contains 1 using random.choice? I tried simple codes like

`random.choice(1 in l)`

or

`random.choice(l, 1=True)`, but none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in method (that would be pretty niche) but you can do the following:

```
import random
my_lists = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,6,7,8],[2,3,4],[1,9,10,13]]
random_list = random.choice([sublist for sublist in my_lists if 1 in sublist])
```

or using `filter`:

```
random_list = random.choice(list(filter(lambda sublist: 1 in sublist, my_lists)))
```

Comment: To the editor: "niche" is a real word, it is not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

Get all the sublists containing 1, and randomly return one.

```
import random

a_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,6,7,8],[2,3,4],[1,9,10,13]]

lists_with_element = [sub_list for sub_list in a_list if 1 in sub_list]

if len(lists_with_element):
    print(lists_with_element[random.randint(0, len(lists_with_element)-1)])
else:
    print("There is no list containing 1")
```

**EDIT:** The above condition will avoid the error if no sublist contains 1
I hope it helps.